# Any one can explain me how to add zero chapters in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

In my thesis work, I need to add zero chapters in table of content like table of content itself with page number, Abstract, acknowledgement, notation and introduction, but by using \tableofcontents I got only the chapters in content list those have chapter numbers. so need suggestions for this issue thanks

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you currently creaate your unnumbered chapters.

Comment: Unnumbered chapters, sections, and so on, are not included in the toc by default. Use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgrment}` right after `\chapter*{Acknowledgement}`, &c.

Comment: @Bernard Could you give an answer based on your comment?  I would have answered with that information if you hadn't commented first. An answer might help someone to not ask a similar question again.

Comment: @PeterWilson: You're right. I've added some words about how to do that automatically with `titlesec`. I don't know `memoir` well enough to know how it can be done, but feel free to add an explanation  for memoir users.

Answer (score 1):

Unnumbered chapters, sections, and so on, are not included in the toc by default. If you want to add them to `toc` for a given level, use `\addcontentsline{toc}{<level>}{<title>}` right after the element where you want it. So, e.g. for a chapter:

```
% The unnumbered chapter
\chapter*{chaptertitle}

% The command to manually add the content entry in toc
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chaptertitle}
```

If you customise the layout of section titles via the `titlesec` package, this inclusion can be automatic with the `numberless` key and the `explicit` option, inserting a similar code in `titleformat` along this line:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}{...}{...}{...}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1} ...}
```